# iOS Development: Adding an "Add Friend" button inside my app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, gamekit, game-center

I'm building an iPhone game that uses Game Center to auto-connect random players looking for a game.  When the match is finished, I wanted to give the players the option to add the opponent as a game center friend so they can play them again in the future.

If I have the opponents GKPlayer data, including their playerID and alias, how can I allow the player to add the opponent as a friend in Game Center via my app?  Or is this only possible through the Game Center app itself?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController` is what you are after? It allows you to send out a friend request (and even has a premade modal view controller)

Comment: yep, that'll work!  not sure why they left that out of the Game Kit programming guide.  thank you very much!

Comment: haha yes i ran across that same problem actually and took me a bit to find the answer.